# Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, cycle for R

Tags: r

Good morning,

I have a problem with my cycle for.

My dataframe is:

```
Name_FD

Column_A   Column_B       Column_C    Column_D  Column_X
Element1  8808864430  88440000011863    Text1      *NA*
Element2  8808877431  88455000045863    Text2      *NA*
Element3  8808886677  88447800011865    Text3      *NA*
Element4  8808888830  88455000045867    Text4      *NA*
Element5  8808888830  88440000011869    Text5      *NA*
Element6  8808888830  88455000045810    Text6      *NA*
Element7  8808889977  88447800011865    Text3      *NA*
Element7  8808889977  88447800011865    Text3      *NA*
```

My code is:

```
Name_FD$Column_X <- rep(NA, length(Name_FD$Column_B))
for (i in Name_FD$Column_B){
 for ( j in Name_FD$Column_B[-1,]) {
    if(i == j) {
      Fonte_Dati$x[i]= 1 
    } else {
      Fonte_Dati$x[i]= 0
   }
 }
}
```

The errors are:

```
Error in Name_FD$Column_B[-1, ] : incorrect number of dimensions

Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "Column_X", value = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,  : 
replacement has 16669 rows, data has 16668
```

The Column_B is ordered from the smallest to the largest.

I 'd like to know, for example,  if the element of Colum_B [3,] is equal with the element of Column_B[4,].

If this is true, I'd like to insert 1 in the Column_X (in the same row of the element of Column_B[4,]) ,  otherwise 0.

**Someone would be so kind to say me where I was wrong.**

Thanks in advance.

Francesco

Comment: Is it possible for you to use `dplyr`'s `lead` and `lag` for this, combined with `ifelse`? `Name_FD %>% mutate( Column_X = ifelse( Column_B == lead( Column_B ), 1, 0 ) )` woulds replace your entire code above

Comment: @Wimpel Thank you for the comment. 
I'm not expert, because I'm Learning R. 
I asked this question because I want to understand the logical and to go over my limits.
If you have a suggest, I'd like to deep it.

Comment: @Francesco Been there... the hardest thing to do, when learning R when you've already got programming experience, is to let go of  the For-loop (in most situattions) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Name_FD <- read.table( text = "Column_A   Column_B       Column_C    Column_D
Element1  8808864430  88440000011863    Text1
Element2  8808877431  88455000045863    Text2
Element3  8808886677  88447800011865    Text3
Element4  8808888830  88455000045867    Text4
Element5  8808888830  88440000011869    Text5
Element6  8808888830  88455000045810    Text6
Element7  8808889977  88447800011865    Text3
Element7  8808889977  88447800011865    Text3", header = TRUE)

library(tidyverse)
Name_FD %>% mutate( Column_X = ifelse( Column_B == lead( Column_B ), 1, 0 ) )
#   Column_A   Column_B    Column_C Column_D Column_X
# 1 Element1 8808864430 8.84400e+13    Text1        0
# 2 Element2 8808877431 8.84550e+13    Text2        0
# 3 Element3 8808886677 8.84478e+13    Text3        0
# 4 Element4 8808888830 8.84550e+13    Text4        1
# 5 Element5 8808888830 8.84400e+13    Text5        1
# 6 Element6 8808888830 8.84550e+13    Text6        0
# 7 Element7 8808889977 8.84478e+13    Text3        1
# 8 Element7 8808889977 8.84478e+13    Text3       NA
```

Comment: Your solution Is clear and simple. 
I have already implemented the solution in my code, and It's working very well.
Thanks again for the solution and for pointing me to the library tidyverse.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a much simpler way of doing this :)

```
library(dplyr)

Name_FD %>% 
  mutate(Column_X = ifelse(Column_B == lead(Column_B), 1, 0)
```

Comment: just like I suggested 6 mins ago ;-) (see comments)

Comment: ah sorry, I didn't see your comment in the time it took me to write this! Franceso, you should accept Wimpel's answer

Comment: No worries.. happens to me all the time :). Funny that I'm on the other side this time.. I 'upgraded' my commant to an answer... so if you want, you can delete your answer, to keer stackoverflow 'clean'.